# Use of unassigned local variable in C#

Tags: c#, loops

I am currently tasked with having a user enter in 5 variables. With the variables I need to create a series of loops to read the variables and assign them to variables. I am required to use only 1 `Console.ReadLine();` I currently have this set up:

```
string userName = ""; 
int v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = 0;  

int i = 1;

while (i <= 5)
{
    int InputCheck = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Please input a number {0} between 10 and 50;", i);
    InputCheck = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (InputCheck >= 10 && InputCheck <= 50) 
    {

        //if (i >= 10 && i <= 50)
            //i++;

        if (i == 1)
        {
            InputCheck = v1;
        }

        else if (i == 2)
        {
            InputCheck = v2;
        }

        else if (i == 3)
        {
            InputCheck = v3;
        }

        else if (i == 4)
        {
            InputCheck = v4;
        }

        else if (i == 5)
        {
            InputCheck = v5;
        }

        if (InputCheck < 10 || InputCheck > 50)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is either to high or to low please re-enter a number:");
        }
    }
```

I am confused as to why I'm getting the error Use of unassigned variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Where** are you getting the error? (You haven't shown how `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, `v4` or `v5` are declared or initialized.)

Comment: My apologies, I didn't copy those in. I declare v1-5 as int's and set them = to 0. I'm getting the errors here: InputCheck = v1; specifically at v1 and all of them except for v5. I'm trying to understand what exactly my while loop is doing to not assign the variables.

Comment: "I am required to use only 1 Console.ReadLine()" Is this homework or an interview question?

Comment: Post v1-5! You say you initialized them but that can't be true because the error tells you you haven't. Do you in principle understand what the error means?

Comment: Your error declaration is out of scope, InputCheck >= 10 && InputCheck <= 50,  if (InputCheck < 10 || InputCheck > 50), this should not be embeded inside the first IF

Comment: All I can say, is that's the wrong way to approach this problem .. what are v1..v5 *supposed* to be? And why is InputCheck used for reading in a user response *and* one of v1..v5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't ever declare v1, v2, v3, etc.  But assuming you declare them elsewhere, if I'm understanding what you're trying to do, your assignments are backwards.

For example, where you're writing

```
InputCheck = v1;
```

You probably want

```
v1 = InputCheck;
```

Then you could go through v1, v2, etc., and do what you want with the values (which would then be what the user typed for input).

Okay...after your recent comment, where you highlight that you initialize v1-5 elsewhere, I'm pretty sure your problem is that your assignments are just reversed, as I said above.  If you need help understanding why, ask.

Comment: If this actually fixes your problem, great. If you still need help understanding why, let me know, and I'll add to the answer.  (I'm assuming this is homework, and normally I wouldn't spell out the answer...but directionality of an assignment is a tough thing to give a hint on.)

Comment: string userName = "";
            int v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = 0;
            float avg;
            float variance;

My apologies on my lack of providing all the material. I'm still trying to understand all this stuff. I tried switching the assignments but later when computing avg and variance I get the same Unassigned local variable error. 

As far as my understanding of the error I believe I do. Essentially it's telling me that the variables are not being assigned in the code. Then are referenced later and because they have nothing assigned to them I get the error?

Comment: @user2084415 `int v1 = 0, v2 = 0, v3 = 0, v4 = 0, v5 = 0;`

Comment: @user2084415 : Romoku is right in the sense that this will get rid of the visible error.  However, your program still won't work, because you're reading the value in from the user into InputCheck, and then promptly writing over it with a value from v1 or v2 etc.  You want to read the value from InputCheck into v1, v2, etc...so you need to reverse your assignment statement.

Comment: That makes more sense now that I see what you guys are saying. I have not set them all equal to 0 and reversed the assignment. I am able to run the code but doesn't do what I want it to do.But as far as my question is concerned you have answer it. I greatly appreciate all the help. Again my apologies on being for a lack of a better term a "noob".

Comment: @user2084415 No problem being a "noob".  Being new but polite and willing to learn is a far better set of qualities than a large amount of experience without them.  If one or more of the answers helped you, you can vote them up by clicking on the up arrow above the number.  Also, if you come back after two days, you can also "accept" a single answer by clicking the checkmark under the answer score...an action that will also gain you 2 points in reputation.

Comment: I have tried doing the up vote thing but because I don't have 15 reputation I am not allowed to do so. But everyone was extremely helpful and again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the variables as

```
 int v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = 0;
```

This initializes v5 but not the others. The error message actually gave a clue to that. Reading the message is the first debugging tool, always.

The message told you "v1 is not initialized". So you go look at where you initialize it (or you aren't yet). This is how to find such a bug.

Actually, I knew that you had this problem with multiple variables in one declaration when you said you assigned 0 to them. The message allowed me to find the problem without even seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) to hold the numbers

```
var numbersList = new List<int>();

while(numbersList.Count <= 5)
{
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if(input >= 10 && input <= 50)
    {
        numbersList.Add(input);
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is either to high or to low please re-enter a number:");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you initialising variables v1,v2,v3,v4,v5 ? Considering you did not initialised variables; you cannot assign unassigned variables to any other local variables, so declare variables v1,v2,v3,v4,v5 = 0 problem will be solved. As mentioned above Using Generic Lists is recommended.